# Error on git submodule update --init

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a main repository with several `git submodule`s.

Lately I came about a new error which I cannot resolve:

```
fatal: Could not switch to '~/git': No such file or directory
Clone of '~/git/MyModule_A.git' into submodule path '.modman/MyModule_A' failed
```

#### What I'm doing

First, I clone the main repo as usual: `git clone /path/to/the/bare/repo.git src`

Then, I run `git submodule update --init` which does correctly register all submodules and they are added to the `.git/config`.

```
Submodule '.modman/MyModule_A' (~/git/MyModule_A.git) registered for path '.modman/MyModule_A'
Submodule '.modman/MyModule_B' (~/git/MyModule_B.git) registered for path '.modman/MyModule_B'
Submodule '.modman/MyModule_C' (~/git/MyModule_C.git) registered for path '.modman/MyModule_C'
fatal: Could not switch to '~/git': No such file or directory
Clone of '~/git/MyModule_A.git' into submodule path '.modman/MyModule_A' failed
```

#### What I have tried so far

- Removing `MyModule_A` submodule from the `.gitmodules` but then the error continues in `MyModule_B`, `MyModule_B` and so on.
- Manually cloning `~/git/MyModule_A.git` into another folder outside the repo which is working fine.
- Checking file permissions which seem to be correct.
- Checking entries in `.gitmodules` for wrong paths, urls or any syntax problems which is not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `~` in your submodule. Git does not know that this stands for `/home/<yourusername>`

If you replace it (in `.gitmodules`) by the absolute path, everything will work.

Comment: Seriously? Damn. I'll try it immediatly.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot!